# SSH Script Joinning

Tags: ssh, scripting

Script1

```
for machine in host name; do
  ssh user@$machine /bin/bash << EOF
uname -a
lscpu  | grep "^CPU(s)"
grep -i memtotal /proc/meminfo
EOF
done
```

Script 2

```
for machine in Host Name; do
  ssh user@$machine /bin/bash<<< 'lshw;cat /etc/resolv.conf'
done
```

I have these two separate script how can i join this script as one

Comment: Put all commands between the two EOF's seperated by ;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the desired result:

```
for machine in host name; do
  ssh user@$machine /bin/bash << EOF
uname -a
lscpu  | grep "^CPU(s)"
grep -i memtotal /proc/meminfo
lshw
cat /etc/resolv.conf'
EOF
done
```

As suggested in comment you need to add the remote commands from second script  between inline delimiters (`EOF` in your case)